# Reinstalling android app without uninstaling

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, uninstallation, reinstall

I have developed my first app using eclipse and uploaded to Amazon app store. Later, I realized some bugs, fixed them and re-uploaded. But, when I want to reinstall app over same/newer version, it says:
"The application you are installing will replace another application. All previous data will be saved" as other normal apks.
"And then it says application not installed." I have signed both versions using same key.

Comment: Look at the logs. It should show you the reason.

Answer (score 0):

when you try to run the app(Let the new project name be AndroidAPP_v2) with all the bugs fixed ,then In eclipse It will show like this :"The application you are installing will replace another application".that means It will replace your old project(let it be AndroidAPP_v1) with new project(AndroidAPP_v2).If you click OK ,it wil automaticall install new app .

This is because both applications have the same package name. If the package name of the two applications are different, you won't get this message.
In fact, if the package name in the Manifest file (in the  tag) matches the package name of another installed application, it will replace it.

Comment: This does not answer the question which was asked - note that the poster's replacement version does not get installed.  Also they are not installing via eclipse/adb.